# Convert a pandas dataframe into a list of named tuple

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, namedtuple

I am looking for the most efficient way to convert a `pandas` `DataFrame` into a list of typed `NamedTuple` - below is a simple example with the expected output.
I would like to get the correct type conversion aligned with the type defined in the dataframe.

```
from typing import NamedTuple
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = [["tom", 10], ["nick", 15], ["juli", 14]]
    People = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "Age"])
    Person = NamedTuple("Person", [("name", str), ("age", int)])
    # ...
    # ...
    # expected output
    # [Person(name='tom', age=10), Person(name='nick', age=15), Person(name='juli', age=14)]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) with `name` parameter and for omit index add `index=false`:

```
tup = list(people.itertuples(name='Person', index=False))
print(tup)
[Person(Name='tom', Age=10), Person(Name='nick', Age=15), Person(Name='juli', Age=14)]
```

If need lowercase values `name` and `age` in namedtuples add `rename`:

```
tup = list(people.rename(columns=str.lower).itertuples(name='Person', index=False))
print(tup)
[Person(name='tom', age=10), Person(name='nick', age=15), Person(name='juli', age=14)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [itertuples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [["tom", 10], ["nick", 15], ["juli", 14]]
people = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "Age"])

result = list(people.itertuples(index=False, name='Person'))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[Person(Name='tom', Age=10), Person(Name='nick', Age=15), Person(Name='juli', Age=14)]
```